# Checking background color in javascript and alert

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Options are in blue color, and with the help of javascript, I am checking whether the option background color is blue or not if it is not blue then execute ahead else alert some text.

```js
function click_option_A() {
 var clr_1_chk = document.getElementById("1");
 //alert(clr_1_chk.style.backgroundColor);
 var clr_2_chk = document.getElementById("2");
 var clr_3_chk = document.getElementById("3");
 var clr_4_chk = document.getElementById("4");
 if(clr_1_chk.style.backgroundColor !== "blue"){
  alert("You have already locked the answer!")
 }
 else if(clr_2_chk.style.backgroundColor !== "blue"){
  alert("You have already locked the answer!")
 }
 else if(clr_3_chk.style.backgroundColor !== "blue"){
  alert("You have already locked the answer!")
 }
 else if(clr_4_chk.style.backgroundColor !== "blue"){
  alert("You have already locked the answer!")
 }
 else{
 var clr = "1";
    var confirm = window.confirm("Are you sure?");
    if (confirm) {
 window.document.getElementById(clr).style.backgroundColor ="yellow";
 var right_answer = "B";
 if(right_answer == "A"){
  //correct_ans();
  setTimeout(correct_ans,3000);
 }
 else{
  setTimeout(wrong_ans,3000);
 }
 }
 }
}
 
function click_option_B() {
 var clr_1_chk = document.getElementById("1");
 var clr_2_chk = document.getElementById("2");
 var clr_3_chk = document.getElementById("3");
 var clr_4_chk = document.getElementById("4");
 if(clr_1_chk.style.backgroundColor !== "blue"){
  alert("You have already locked the answer!")
 }
 else if(clr_2_chk.style.backgroundColor !== "blue"){
  alert("You have already locked the answer!")
 }
 else if(clr_3_chk.style.backgroundColor !== "blue"){
  alert("You have already locked the answer!")
 }
 else if(clr_4_chk.style.backgroundColor !== "blue"){
  alert("You have already locked the answer!")
 }
 else{
 var clr = "2";
    var confirm = window.confirm("Are you Sure?");
    if (confirm) {
 window.document.getElementById(clr).style.backgroundColor ="yellow";
 var right_answer = "B";
 if(right_answer == "B"){
  //correct_ans();
  setTimeout(correct_ans,3000);
 }
 else{
  setTimeout(wrong_ans,3000);
 }
 }
 }
}
function click_option_C() {
 var clr_1_chk = document.getElementById("1");
 var clr_2_chk = document.getElementById("2");
 var clr_3_chk = document.getElementById("3");
 var clr_4_chk = document.getElementById("4");
 if(clr_1_chk.style.backgroundColor !== "blue"){
  alert("You have already locked the answer!")
 }
 else if(clr_2_chk.style.backgroundColor !== "blue"){
  alert("You have already locked the answer!")
 }
 else if(clr_3_chk.style.backgroundColor !== "blue"){
  alert("You have already locked the answer!")
 }
 else if(clr_4_chk.style.backgroundColor !== "blue"){
  alert("You have already locked the answer!")
 }
 else{
 var clr = "3";
    var confirm = window.confirm("Are you Sure?");
    if (confirm) {
 window.document.getElementById(clr).style.backgroundColor ="yellow";
 var right_answer = "B";
 if(right_answer == "C"){
  //correct_ans();
  setTimeout(correct_ans,3000);
 }
 else{
  setTimeout(wrong_ans,3000);
 }
 }
 }
}
function click_option_D() {
 var clr_1_chk = document.getElementById("1");
 var clr_2_chk = document.getElementById("2");
 var clr_3_chk = document.getElementById("3");
 var clr_4_chk = document.getElementById("4");
 if(clr_1_chk.style.backgroundColor !== "blue"){
  alert("You have already locked the answer!")
 }
 else if(clr_2_chk.style.backgroundColor !== "blue"){
  alert("You have already locked the answer!")
 }
 else if(clr_3_chk.style.backgroundColor !== "blue"){
  alert("You have already locked the answer!")
 }
 else if(clr_4_chk.style.backgroundColor !== "blue"){
  alert("You have already locked the answer!")
 }
 else{
 var clr = "4";
    var confirm = window.confirm("Are you Sure?");
    if (confirm) {
 window.document.getElementById(clr).style.backgroundColor ="yellow";
 var right_answer = "B";
 if(right_answer == "D"){
  //correct_ans();
  setTimeout(correct_ans,3000);
 }
 else{
  setTimeout(wrong_ans,3000);
 }
 }
 }
}
 
function correct_ans(){
 var clr_1_chk = document.getElementById("1");
 var clr_2_chk = document.getElementById("2");
 var clr_3_chk = document.getElementById("3");
 var clr_4_chk = document.getElementById("4");
 if(clr_1_chk.style.backgroundColor !== "blue"){
  var clr = "1";
 }
 else if(clr_2_chk.style.backgroundColor !== "blue"){
  var clr = "2";
 }
 else if(clr_3_chk.style.backgroundColor !== "blue"){
  var clr = "3";
 }
 else{
  var clr = "4";
 }
 //alert('correct');
 document.getElementById(clr).style.backgroundColor ="green";
}
function wrong_ans(){
 var clr_1_chk = document.getElementById("1");
 var clr_2_chk = document.getElementById("2");
 var clr_3_chk = document.getElementById("3");
 var clr_4_chk = document.getElementById("4");
 if(clr_1_chk.style.backgroundColor !== "blue"){
  var clr = "1";
 }
 else if(clr_2_chk.style.backgroundColor !== "blue"){
  var clr = "2";
 }
 else if(clr_3_chk.style.backgroundColor !== "blue"){
  var clr = "3";
 }
 else{
  var clr = "4";
 }
 document.getElementById(clr).style.backgroundColor ="red";
}
```

```css
td{
 background-color: blue;
 color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

<!--<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal">-->
     
 <table class="table table-bordered table-responsive">
 
    <tr class="text-center">
     <td colspan="2">Who was First Prime Minister of India?(15304)</td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
     <td id="1" onclick="click_option_A()">A) M K Gandhi</td>
        <td id="2" onclick="click_option_B()">B) Jawaharlal Nehru</td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
     <td id="3" onclick="click_option_C()">C) Rajendra Prasad</td>
  <td id="4" onclick="click_option_D()">D) Chandra Shekhar Azad</td>
    </tr>
    
    </table>
    
<!--</form>-->

</div>
```

I tried the above code, but it always alert me that I have locked the answer but I haven't.

Options are in blue color, and with the help of javascript, I am checking whether the option background color is blue or not if it is not blue then execute ahead else alert some text.

Comment: maybe its not "blue" maybe its some hex color which matches to blue such as 0000ff or 0000fd or whatsoever check that first !

Comment: I checked the color of the elements in the console by running ```document.getElementById("1").style.backgroundColor``` and this returned an empty string. Which is why your ```!== "blue"``` is failing.

Comment: Unrelated to the question, your code has a bunch of duplicate code and a number of methods that seem to be doing the exact same thing (with small variations), you can refactor these methods into a single method that serves the same purpose for all answers.

Comment: @YamenNassif I tried with `#0000ff" to, but then also it says locked!

Comment: @yarwest I will refactor the script later after completion of writing script. Why it returned an empty string?

Comment: inspect the element in browser and see what color is there

Comment: @PBMusics it maybe that backgroundColor is not applied but the background is

Comment: You should not base your actions on background color. Rather use a class or a data attribute.

Comment: You should do something to simplify your javascript. It's 4 times the same thing!

Comment: You need to use `getComputedStyle()` and check against rgb values; see my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While Prajwal is on the right track his answer is not quite complete. `getComputedStyle()` will return an RGB value when `backgroundColor` is called. You will need to check against that instead of the string "blue". So in your case `getComputedStyle(clr_1_chk).backgroundColor === "rgb(0, 0, 255)";`

However, best practice would be to store your questions in an array of javascript objects. There, you could have the correct answer stored and whether or not the question is locked. As requested I have mocked up a quick dummy example of what that code would look like. I'm essentially using JS to create the HTML. I didn't include the `setTimeout` that you requested but I'm sure you can add this easily. Please make sure you include the HTML, CSS, and JS for this to work. Please note the error after question 4 is just saying there are no more questions to generate. Hope this gives you something to start with:

```js
var questions = [{
    questionId: "question1",
    answerId: "B",
    question: "Who was First Prime Minister of India?(15304)",
    options: ["A) M K Gandhi", "B) Jawaharlal Nehru", "C) Rajendra Prasad", "D) Chandra Shekhar Azad"],
    answer: "B) Jawaharlal Nehru",
    locked: false
  },
  {
    questionId: "question2",
    answerId: "D",
    question: "What is 2 + 2",
    options: ["A) 1", "B) 2", "C) 3", "D) 4"],
    answer: "D) 4",
    locked: false
  },
  {
    questionId: "question3",
    question: "What is 2 - 1",
    answerId: "A",
    options: ["A) 1", "B) 2", "C) 3", "D) 4"],
    answer: "A) 1",
    locked: false
  },
  {
    questionId: "question4",
    answerId: "C",
    question: "What is 2 + 4",
    options: ["A) 1", "B) 2", "C) 6", "D) 4"],
    answer: "C) 6",
    locked: false
  }
];

var allHtml;
var table = document.getElementById("test");
var i = 0;
document.querySelector("#start").innerHTML = `<button onclick="startTest()">START TEST</button>`;


function generateQuestion(question) {
  i += 1;
  var newQuestion = `
        <tr class="text-center">
            <td colspan="2">${question.question}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="A${i}" class="${question.questionId}" onclick="onSelect(event)">${question.options[0]}</td>
            <td id="B${i}" class="${question.questionId}" onclick="onSelect(event)">${question.options[1]}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="C${i}" class="${question.questionId}" onclick="onSelect(event)">${question.options[2]}</td>
            <td id="D${i}" class="${question.questionId}" onclick="onSelect(event)">${question.options[3]}</td>
        </tr>
    `;
  allHtml = table.innerHTML + newQuestion;
  table.innerHTML = allHtml;
}

function onSelect(e) {
  var selection = e.currentTarget;
  var questionId = e.currentTarget.className;
  var currentQuestion = questions.find(function(q) {
    return q.questionId == questionId
  });
  if (currentQuestion.locked) {
    alert("Question already answered");
    return;
  } else if (currentQuestion.answer === e.currentTarget.innerText) {
    alert("Correct!!!");
    currentQuestion.locked = true;
    selection.classList.add('correct');
  } else {
    alert("Incorrect...");
    currentQuestion.locked = true;
    selection.classList.add('incorrect');
    document.getElementById(currentQuestion.answerId + i).classList.add('correct');
  }
  generateQuestion(questions[i]);
}

function startTest() {
  generateQuestion(questions[i]);
  document.querySelector("#start").innerHTML = '';
}
```

```css
.correct {
  background-color: green;
}

.incorrect {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="start"></div>
<table id="test"></table>
```

What I'm doing here is setting the answer classes to the question id in the object. Then using that I get the correct question out of the answers array. I check to make sure the answer is not locked, then I get the innerText of the answer and check that against the answer id in the object. Lastly I lock the question after the user answers and apply the css classes to the correct answer and the incorrect selection if applicable. Once all that is done, I call `generateQuestion` to create the next question.

And here is the updated code from your question that works correctly. Also, although it's not updated in my answer you really should rename your id's. It's best to begin them with a letter [A-Za-z].:

```js
function click_option_A() {
  var clr_1_chk = document.getElementById("1");
  //alert(clr_1_chk.style.backgroundColor);
  var clr_2_chk = document.getElementById("2");
  var clr_3_chk = document.getElementById("3");
  var clr_4_chk = document.getElementById("4");
  console.log(getComputedStyle(clr_1_chk).backgroundColor);
  if (getComputedStyle(clr_1_chk).backgroundColor != "rgb(0, 0, 255)") {
    alert("You have already locked the answer!")
  } else if (getComputedStyle(clr_2_chk).backgroundColor != "rgb(0, 0, 255)") {
    alert("You have already locked the answer!")
  } else if (getComputedStyle(clr_3_chk).backgroundColor != "rgb(0, 0, 255)") {
    alert("You have already locked the answer!")
  } else if (getComputedStyle(clr_4_chk).backgroundColor != "rgb(0, 0, 255)") {
    alert("You have already locked the answer!")
  } else {
    var clr = "1";
    var confirm = window.confirm("Are you sure?");
    if (confirm) {
      window.document.getElementById(clr).style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
      var right_answer = "B";
      if (right_answer == "A") {
        //correct_ans();
        setTimeout(correct_ans, 3000);
      } else {
        setTimeout(wrong_ans, 3000);
      }
    }
  }
}

function click_option_B() {
  var clr_1_chk = document.getElementById("1");
  var clr_2_chk = document.getElementById("2");
  var clr_3_chk = document.getElementById("3");
  var clr_4_chk = document.getElementById("4");
  if (getComputedStyle(clr_1_chk).backgroundColor != "rgb(0, 0, 255)") {
    alert("You have already locked the answer!")
  } else if (getComputedStyle(clr_2_chk).backgroundColor != "rgb(0, 0, 255)") {
    alert("You have already locked the answer!")
  } else if (getComputedStyle(clr_3_chk).backgroundColor != "rgb(0, 0, 255)") {
    alert("You have already locked the answer!")
  } else if (getComputedStyle(clr_4_chk).backgroundColor != "rgb(0, 0, 255)") {
    alert("You have already locked the answer!")
  } else {
    var clr = "2";
    var confirm = window.confirm("Are you Sure?");
    if (confirm) {
      window.document.getElementById(clr).style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
      var right_answer = "B";
      if (right_answer == "B") {
        //correct_ans();
        setTimeout(correct_ans, 3000);
      } else {
        setTimeout(wrong_ans, 3000);
      }
    }
  }
}

function click_option_C() {
  var clr_1_chk = document.getElementById("1");
  var clr_2_chk = document.getElementById("2");
  var clr_3_chk = document.getElementById("3");
  var clr_4_chk = document.getElementById("4");
  if (getComputedStyle(clr_1_chk).backgroundColor != "rgb(0, 0, 255)") {
    alert("You have already locked the answer!")
  } else if (getComputedStyle(clr_2_chk).backgroundColor != "rgb(0, 0, 255)") {
    alert("You have already locked the answer!")
  } else if (getComputedStyle(clr_3_chk).backgroundColor != "rgb(0, 0, 255)") {
    alert("You have already locked the answer!")
  } else if (getComputedStyle(clr_4_chk).backgroundColor != "rgb(0, 0, 255)") {
    alert("You have already locked the answer!")
  } else {
    var clr = "3";
    var confirm = window.confirm("Are you Sure?");
    if (confirm) {
      window.document.getElementById(clr).style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
      var right_answer = "B";
      if (right_answer == "C") {
        //correct_ans();
        setTimeout(correct_ans, 3000);
      } else {
        setTimeout(wrong_ans, 3000);
      }
    }
  }
}

function click_option_D() {
  var clr_1_chk = document.getElementById("1");
  var clr_2_chk = document.getElementById("2");
  var clr_3_chk = document.getElementById("3");
  var clr_4_chk = document.getElementById("4");
  if (getComputedStyle(clr_1_chk).backgroundColor != "rgb(0, 0, 255)") {
    alert("You have already locked the answer!")
  } else if (getComputedStyle(clr_2_chk).backgroundColor != "rgb(0, 0, 255)") {
    alert("You have already locked the answer!")
  } else if (getComputedStyle(clr_3_chk).backgroundColor != "rgb(0, 0, 255)") {
    alert("You have already locked the answer!")
  } else if (getComputedStyle(clr_4_chk).backgroundColor != "rgb(0, 0, 255)") {
    alert("You have already locked the answer!")
  } else {
    var clr = "4";
    var confirm = window.confirm("Are you Sure?");
    if (confirm) {
      window.document.getElementById(clr).style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
      var right_answer = "B";
      if (right_answer == "D") {
        //correct_ans();
        setTimeout(correct_ans, 3000);
      } else {
        setTimeout(wrong_ans, 3000);
      }
    }
  }
}

function correct_ans() {
  var clr_1_chk = document.getElementById("1");
  var clr_2_chk = document.getElementById("2");
  var clr_3_chk = document.getElementById("3");
  var clr_4_chk = document.getElementById("4");
  if (getComputedStyle(clr_1_chk).backgroundColor != "rgb(0, 0, 255)") {
    var clr = "1";
  } else if (getComputedStyle(clr_2_chk).backgroundColor != "rgb(0, 0, 255)") {
    var clr = "2";
  } else if (getComputedStyle(clr_3_chk).backgroundColor != "rgb(0, 0, 255)") {
    var clr = "3";
  } else {
    var clr = "4";
  }
  //alert('correct');
  document.getElementById(clr).style.backgroundColor = "green";
}

function wrong_ans() {
  var clr_1_chk = document.getElementById("1");
  var clr_2_chk = document.getElementById("2");
  var clr_3_chk = document.getElementById("3");
  var clr_4_chk = document.getElementById("4");
  if (getComputedStyle(clr_1_chk).backgroundColor != "rgb(0, 0, 255)") {
    var clr = "1";
  } else if (getComputedStyle(clr_2_chk).backgroundColor != "rgb(0, 0, 255)") {
    var clr = "2";
  } else if (getComputedStyle(clr_3_chk).backgroundColor != "rgb(0, 0, 255)") {
    var clr = "3";
  } else {
    var clr = "4";
  }
  document.getElementById(clr).style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
```

```css
td {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">

  <!--<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal">-->

  <table class="table table-bordered table-responsive">

    <tr class="text-center">
      <td colspan="2">Who was First Prime Minister of India?(15304)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="1" onclick="click_option_A()">A) M K Gandhi</td>
      <td id="2" onclick="click_option_B()">B) Jawaharlal Nehru</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="3" onclick="click_option_C()">C) Rajendra Prasad</td>
      <td id="4" onclick="click_option_D()">D) Chandra Shekhar Azad</td>
    </tr>

  </table>

  <!--</form>-->

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the time and answer both answers worked for me, read the last two lines of Prajwal's answer and [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50021849/checking-background-color-in-javascript-and-alert#comment87060506_50022125)

Comment: @PBMusics I've added a quick example of how to check the answer with a javascript object

Comment: Nice example of the javascript object, but my question will not be displayed all at once, what will be the activity:- showing question and option -> user chooses the option -> lock the chosen option -> after 3 seconds change the color (if A is right and user locked A then that option will be green and if user locked any other than A, then locked answer should be red and right answer green) -> then i will show one more activity. And then it repeats. **Can I get a dummy example of the process in the javascript object?**

Comment: Yeah, I'll mock up something real quick.

Comment: @PBMusics, sorry for the delay. I got a little busy with something else but I got the basic concept for what you want. You can add a `setTimeout` for the requested delay pretty easily.

Comment: I [edited](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FQRKLIT0W82G) your code as per my need, all went well. After adding styles to the question, when the user selects the wrong option it does not show right answer. (I think so, it is because of removing class `question1`.) **The changes I made is in `function onSelect(e)`**.

Comment: I think you ran your script, [here is my script](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FQRKLIT0W82G). Did this worked fine? (choose the wrong answer for testing)

Comment: I edited your code a little bit. Instead of using `classList.add()` I'm using `setAttribute`. This way the other classes are overridden. You can check it out here: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FQROC8FSFWDV

Comment: Sorry. There was a syntax error in the previous link. Try this: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FQRTIVN0B9RF

Comment: Hello, what to do if I want to lock anyone option say **`A`**? I tried: `document.getElementById("A1").locked = true;`, but I failed to execute it.

Comment: In the onSelect function I get the selection using e.currentTarget. You can you can set the class of the selection to locked instead of using getElementById. Then you can see if locked is in the class list. This is not best practice though. Best practice would be to set the options array in the question object to an array of objects. Then you could have a property inside each option of locked and set it to true or false. This would take a bit of reworking the code though

Comment: I am using the [same code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50021849/checking-background-color-in-javascript-and-alert/50022609?noredirect=1#comment87154395_50022609), with the addition I have added a life-line called 50-50 (meaning remove two wrong option), I had built a function for calling that life-line, the only thing is left that the two wrong option should be locked when it life-line is called, therefore **How to lock anyone option**. Hope you understood the concept.

Comment: If you put it in a jsfiddle or something and send me the link I'll take a look at it.

Comment: I have put the codes at [W3Schools' Try Editor](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FQW70HCE035W), run that code after options are displayed click on button `Life_Line` and then click on the option. `function ll_50_50()` starts on line number **309**.

Comment: In this link I think it is working how you expect. You were locking the question which is why all options were being locked; I didn't need to to get it working but I adjusted the options array to be an object array to include the locked option. This way you can lock the options and check against them as you see fit. Notice that instead of just using `question.options[0]` to populate the options, I'm using `question.options[0].a` https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FQW70HCE035W

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170168/discussion-between-pb-musics-and-cory-kleiser).

Comment: Sorry wrong link, try this: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FQWC2216Q3DP

Answer (score 4):

The reason you are not getting the style as `blue` here, but empty string, Because `element.style` returns only ***in-line stylings***, not those defined by CSS.

If you need CSS styling you will have to obtain computed styles using  `window.getComputedStyle(<element>)`.

More info at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style)

In the below snippet, I've set up inline styling for `td`. And hence you will get the style as `blue`.

```js
function click_option_A() {
 var clr_1_chk = document.getElementById("1");
 //alert(clr_1_chk.style.backgroundColor);
 var clr_2_chk = document.getElementById("2");
 var clr_3_chk = document.getElementById("3");
 var clr_4_chk = document.getElementById("4");
 if(clr_1_chk.style.backgroundColor !== "blue"){
  alert("You have already locked the answer!")
 }
 else if(clr_2_chk.style.backgroundColor !== "blue"){
  alert("You have already locked the answer!")
 }
 else if(clr_3_chk.style.backgroundColor !== "blue"){
  alert("You have already locked the answer!")
 }
 else if(clr_4_chk.style.backgroundColor !== "blue"){
  alert("You have already locked the answer!")
 }
 else{
 var clr = "1";
    var confirm = window.confirm("Are you sure?");
    if (confirm) {
 window.document.getElementById(clr).style.backgroundColor ="yellow";
 var right_answer = "B";
 if(right_answer == "A"){
  //correct_ans();
  setTimeout(correct_ans,3000);
 }
 else{
  setTimeout(wrong_ans,3000);
 }
 }
 }
}
 
function click_option_B() {
 var clr_1_chk = document.getElementById("1");
 var clr_2_chk = document.getElementById("2");
 var clr_3_chk = document.getElementById("3");
 var clr_4_chk = document.getElementById("4");
 if(clr_1_chk.style.backgroundColor !== "blue"){
  alert("You have already locked the answer!")
 }
 else if(clr_2_chk.style.backgroundColor !== "blue"){
  alert("You have already locked the answer!")
 }
 else if(clr_3_chk.style.backgroundColor !== "blue"){
  alert("You have already locked the answer!")
 }
 else if(clr_4_chk.style.backgroundColor !== "blue"){
  alert("You have already locked the answer!")
 }
 else{
 var clr = "2";
    var confirm = window.confirm("Are you Sure?");
    if (confirm) {
 window.document.getElementById(clr).style.backgroundColor ="yellow";
 var right_answer = "B";
 if(right_answer == "B"){
  //correct_ans();
  setTimeout(correct_ans,3000);
 }
 else{
  setTimeout(wrong_ans,3000);
 }
 }
 }
}
function click_option_C() {
 var clr_1_chk = document.getElementById("1");
 var clr_2_chk = document.getElementById("2");
 var clr_3_chk = document.getElementById("3");
 var clr_4_chk = document.getElementById("4");
 if(clr_1_chk.style.backgroundColor !== "blue"){
  alert("You have already locked the answer!")
 }
 else if(clr_2_chk.style.backgroundColor !== "blue"){
  alert("You have already locked the answer!")
 }
 else if(clr_3_chk.style.backgroundColor !== "blue"){
  alert("You have already locked the answer!")
 }
 else if(clr_4_chk.style.backgroundColor !== "blue"){
  alert("You have already locked the answer!")
 }
 else{
 var clr = "3";
    var confirm = window.confirm("Are you Sure?");
    if (confirm) {
 window.document.getElementById(clr).style.backgroundColor ="yellow";
 var right_answer = "B";
 if(right_answer == "C"){
  //correct_ans();
  setTimeout(correct_ans,3000);
 }
 else{
  setTimeout(wrong_ans,3000);
 }
 }
 }
}
function click_option_D() {
 var clr_1_chk = document.getElementById("1");
 var clr_2_chk = document.getElementById("2");
 var clr_3_chk = document.getElementById("3");
 var clr_4_chk = document.getElementById("4");
 if(clr_1_chk.style.backgroundColor !== "blue"){
  alert("You have already locked the answer!")
 }
 else if(clr_2_chk.style.backgroundColor !== "blue"){
  alert("You have already locked the answer!")
 }
 else if(clr_3_chk.style.backgroundColor !== "blue"){
  alert("You have already locked the answer!")
 }
 else if(clr_4_chk.style.backgroundColor !== "blue"){
  alert("You have already locked the answer!")
 }
 else{
 var clr = "4";
    var confirm = window.confirm("Are you Sure?");
    if (confirm) {
 window.document.getElementById(clr).style.backgroundColor ="yellow";
 var right_answer = "B";
 if(right_answer == "D"){
  //correct_ans();
  setTimeout(correct_ans,3000);
 }
 else{
  setTimeout(wrong_ans,3000);
 }
 }
 }
}
 
function correct_ans(){
 var clr_1_chk = document.getElementById("1");
 var clr_2_chk = document.getElementById("2");
 var clr_3_chk = document.getElementById("3");
 var clr_4_chk = document.getElementById("4");
 if(clr_1_chk.style.backgroundColor !== "blue"){
  var clr = "1";
 }
 else if(clr_2_chk.style.backgroundColor !== "blue"){
  var clr = "2";
 }
 else if(clr_3_chk.style.backgroundColor !== "blue"){
  var clr = "3";
 }
 else{
  var clr = "4";
 }
 //alert('correct');
 document.getElementById(clr).style.backgroundColor ="green";
}
function wrong_ans(){
 var clr_1_chk = document.getElementById("1");
 var clr_2_chk = document.getElementById("2");
 var clr_3_chk = document.getElementById("3");
 var clr_4_chk = document.getElementById("4");
 if(clr_1_chk.style.backgroundColor !== "blue"){
  var clr = "1";
 }
 else if(clr_2_chk.style.backgroundColor !== "blue"){
  var clr = "2";
 }
 else if(clr_3_chk.style.backgroundColor !== "blue"){
  var clr = "3";
 }
 else{
  var clr = "4";
 }
 document.getElementById(clr).style.backgroundColor ="red";
}
```

```css
td{
 background-color: blue;
 color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

<!--<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal">-->
     
 <table class="table table-bordered table-responsive">
 
    <tr class="text-center">
     <td colspan="2">Who was First Prime Minister of India?(15304)</td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
     <td id="1"  style="background-color: blue;color: white;" onclick="click_option_A()">A) M K Gandhi</td>
        <td  style="background-color: blue;color: white;" id="2" onclick="click_option_B()">B) Jawaharlal Nehru</td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
     <td style="background-color: blue;color: white;" id="3" onclick="click_option_C()">C) Rajendra Prasad</td>
  <td style="background-color: blue;color: white;" id="4" onclick="click_option_D()">D) Chandra Shekhar Azad</td>
    </tr>
    
    </table>
    
<!--</form>-->

</div>
```

---

I would suggest you to keep some JS object to check the options and provide correct answer. It is not advised to refer object style to get user option.

Comment: Can I get an example of JS object with the same thing?